# Android: How to determine if a touch event is in a circle?

Tags: android, touch, geometry

I want to play a media when i touch a circular area, but how can I could determine that my touch position is in the circle?

So far I extend a `view` and implement the `onTouchEvent`, and I need the algorithm for deciding if the position is inside or outside the circle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should take position of the view with [View.getX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getX%28%29) and [View.getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getY%28%29) to get `x` and `y` of the upper left corner and also assuming You know the radius (or able to obtain width/height of the view to determine radius). After that, obtain `xTouch` and `yTouch` using [MotionEvent.getX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28%29) and [MotionEvent.getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY%28%29) and check if:

```
double centerX = x + radius;
double centerY = y + radius;
double distanceX = xTouch - centerX;
double distanceY = yTouch - centerY;

boolean isInside() {
    return (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) <= radius * radius;
}
```

The formula is just interpretation of schools geometry for determining if dot is inside circle area or not. Refer to [circle equation for Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) for more details.

Values explanation is:

`(x + radius)` and `(y + radius)` is the center of circle.

`(xTouch - (x + radius))` is distance from touch point to center by X.

`(yTouch - (y + radius))` is distance from touch point to center by Y.

Comment: Is anyone able to explain this logic please? It works great, just would be even better with some explanation of the logic

Comment: @JoeMaher added some more details regarding geometry explanation

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this, and a little simpler I think, is to use the distance between two points formula and compare that distance to your radius. If the calculated distance is less than the radius then the touch is inside your circle.

**Here the code**

```
// Distance between two points formula
float touchRadius = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(touchX - mViewCenterPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(touchY - mViewCenterPoint.y, 2));

if (touchRadius < mCircleRadius)
{
    // TOUCH INSIDE THE CIRCLE!
}
```