# Moving onDraw circles with finger

Tags: java, android

I am looking to implement the ability to move already created `onDraw` circles within my android program. This is my [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul7yx.png), id like to be able to move every circle with on screen touch. Below is my current *CustomView* class that draws the circles and the grid. I know that I need an `onTouch` listener added to this class, but I am a bit confused as to how to go about it after adding the listener.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    // private  fields  that    are necessary   for rendering   the view
    private boolean touches[]; //   which   fingers providing   input
    private float touchx[]; //  x   position    of  each    touch
    private float touchy[]; //  y   position    of  each    touch
    private int first; //   the first   touch   to  be  rendered
    private boolean touch; //   do  we  have    at  least   on

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAINT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 8;
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 8;

    private int numRows = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROWS, numColumns = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
    blackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    redPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), 0, redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), 0, getMeasuredHeight(), redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), 0, 0, redPaint);


    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(width * i / numColumns, 0, width * i / numColumns, height, redPaint);
    }

    // Horizontal lines
    for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, height * i / numRows, width, height * i / numRows, redPaint);
    }


    canvas.drawCircle(60, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(190, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(320, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(450, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(580, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(710, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(840, 220, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(970, 220, 40, blackPaint);


    canvas.drawCircle(60, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(190, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(320, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(450, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(580, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(710, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(840, 70, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(970, 70, 40, blackPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(60, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(190, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(320, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(450, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(580, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(710, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(840, 980, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(970, 980, 40, blackPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(60, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(190, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(320, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(450, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(580, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(710, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(840, 1130, 40, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(970, 1130, 40, blackPaint);

  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228313/android-how-to-determine-if-a-touch-event-is-in-a-circle. detect if the touch happens within the circles and then do what is required. redraw the cricle with new coordinates by calling invalidate to refresh the view

Comment: formatting changes